# How to disable product or enable compare in prestashop 1.6?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How to enable or disable the product compare option in the prestashop 1.6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can able to enable or disable the product compare option using the following location in backend.

**"Preference -> Products -> Product comparison"**

**To Disable:**

Set the value "0" to disable product comparison.

**To enable:**

Set the maximum number(like "3") of products want to compare.